non-stoquastic vs quantum annealer
Why non-stoquastic Hamiltonian is difficult to implement for a quantum annealer? In another way, why stoquastic vs non-stoquastic matters?
Thanks.

Isn’t the standard answer related to the sign problem?

yes, it seems.  but @MarkSpinelli  could you elaborate? help me with the right basic info?  thanks

I was about to reply with my understanding of the meaning of "stoquastic", along with some recent excitement from Gilyén, Hastings, and Vazirani, but that doesn't explain anything about quantum annealers, which I don't know much about.  So instead I'd point you to @Norbert's answer here to a similar question on phys.SE.
